# PHP: Strings not working in external file

Tags: php, mysql

I have written up some strings in an external file so I don't have strings everywhere, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Init.inc.php**

```
$get_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($get_user);
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($user_data['id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($user_data['username']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($user_data['email']);
```

**Session.php**

```
require("includes/config.php");
require("includes/init.inc.php");
echo "Hello", $username, $email;
```

It should output the username and the email address of the user.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you use `session_start()` ?

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't add it in the code,

Comment: What goes wrong? Do the strings end up blank? What values are fetched into `$user_data`?

Comment: The strings return blank: I have edited the file.

Comment: Try using `var_dump($user_data);` does the array contain anything?

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson "bool(false)"

Comment: try using session_start() in the external file?

Comment: @SpiderLinked I added session_start(); inside the external file and echo'd $username in session.php and it returned: 

array(28) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(5) "Billy" ["firstname"]=> string(5) "Billy" [2]=> string(6) "lastname" ["lastname"]=> string(6) "lastname" [3]=> string(5) "Billy" ["username"]=> string(5) "Billy" [4]=> string(32)...

Comment: @SpiderLinked Nevermind that huge array I still had var_dump on haha, it returns the username now, Thanks!

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt Please remember to accept an answer or add your own and accept it.

Comment: @SpiderLinked Also, wouldn't having session_start; inside the external file create an exploit or something malicious?

Comment: i don't think so...but anyway...you need to start the session in order to use session related variables like $_SESSION['user']..you can destroy it at the end of the file if you want to bec. you only need to use it to access those variables

Answer (score 0):

It works if you define as GLOBAL

```
require("includes/config.php");
require("includes/init.inc.php");
global $username, $email;
echo "Hello", $username, $email;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the variables in includes you only can reach then if you define global.

Comment: That's for functions, included variables are always on global scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Make sure you have added the `session_start()`

```
 require("includes/Init.inc.php");
```

instead of

```
require("includes/init.inc.php");
```

Comment: `session_start()` is what I suspect, for `require`, he will get an error anyways

Answer (score 0):

f you have added     session_start()

then call it like this

```
echo "Hello". $username .",". $email;
```

Comment: third answer, `,` is fine when you use `echo`, you need `.` when you want to concatenate the string and you want to assign that to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe errors are not shown in your php configuration

Try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` to the beginning of Session.php

Answer (score 0):

This is my comment turned into an answer (added for reference):

Add

```
      session_start();
```

at the begining of the included file in order to use $_SESSION['user'] or any session related variables... you can latter destroy (using session_destroy(); ) it if you need/want to, while it is only needed for the above stated purpouse.